# JSF session bean target unreachable in process

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, viewexpiredexception

I have a JSF 1.2 web application that has been in use for several years.  Over the last couple days I've seen many 'Target unreachable' errors while users are processing.

The underlying objects on my session scoped beans seem to be null.  This happens between JSF pages so the object is definetely not null, the user hits a `h:commandButton`, we do some validation and then forward to the next page where we hit the error.  The users are able to try again in a few minutes and it works fine.  The code hasn't changed for several months.

Could there be some kind of memory limit or number of users I'm hitting?  My `web.xml` has the `com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession` context-parm set to 15 like default.  I thought if that was exceeded it would throw a `ViewExpiredException` though, which is not what I'm seeing.

Is there any other way to troubleshoot why the session scoped bean variables would be getting reset?

Thanks

Comment: @summit: library/framework/API names like "JSF" are not code, so please do not format them as code!

Comment: You should be tracking the JSESSION_ID (the appserver-generated unique identifier for sessions) between the various requests. Look in your browser console for any anomalies/ sudden creation of new JSESSION_IDs between requests